# SQL - Cannot get JOIN do what I want

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables:
tab1 having customer ID, a start date and a end date
tab2 having type 1 transaction data: customer ID, transaction date, transaction amount
tab3 having type 2 transaction data: customer ID, transaction date, transaction amount

I want to have a table with the following columns:
col1: player_ID
col2: sum of transaction amount from tab2 (type 1 transaction) occurred between the associated start date and end date from tab1
col3: sum of transaction amount from tab3 (type 2 transaction) occurred between the associated start date and end date from tab1

I got it work if I join tab1 and tab2 by joining the two tables on player ID and using:

```
sum(case when (transaction date >= start date AND transaction date <= end date) then transaction amount else 0 end)
```

But when I join also tab3 on player ID, the previous sum gives me different and much higher (and wrong) values. I'm sure I'm making mistakes on the cartesian product I'm creating, but

Instead of join tab3 I also tried with subquery on tab3, but my netezza sql did not allowed me to do that...

I have no idea how to fix it...

****UPDATE AFTER YOUR COMMENTS*****

This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT lm.player_id,
/*SALES BEFORE limit starts */
sum(case when (dt.cal_day_dt<=lm.hit_time and dt.cal_day_dt>lm.hit_time-14) then  .sales_amount else 0 end) as sales_before14,

/*SALES BEFORE limit starts - Control group */
(select sum(amount_won) from IA_PLAYER_WINNERS where transaction_time<=lm.hit_time and transaction_time>lm.hit_time-14) as sales_before14_control
from (  
select player_id, min(hit_time) as hit_time, re_enable_date, limits
from IA_PLAYER_SPENDING_LIMITS
where limit_type='W'
group by player_id, re_enable_date, limits
) lm
join IA_PLAYER_SALES_HOURLY s ON lm.player_id = s.player_id
join IA_DATES dt ON s.date_key = dt.date_key
join IA_PRODUCTS pr ON s.product_key = pr.product_key
where lm.hit_time >='2014-03-25' and lm.re_enable_date<='2014-05-24'
group by lm.player_id, lm.re_enable_date, lm.limits
order by lm.player_id;
```

I get this error: "Relation 'LM' does not exist"

When I tried to eliminate the reference to LM, I got this new error:
 "Sub-SELECT uses un-GROUPed attribute "*RSS*".#HIT_TIME#0xa69fca4 from outer query"

Comment: Please show us your complete statement. Your example does not contain a join (it's not even a complete/correct statement)

Answer (score 0):

You need two completely separate queries with a very similar structure, one for tab2 and one for tab3 (or two subqueries, or two or three views, depending on what your SQL dialect allows), because your tab2 and tab3 are completely unrelated; you cannot join them in any sensible way.

What happens in your tests is, probably, that the join of three tables repeats rows in tab2 for each row in tab3 having the same customer_id and vice versa, summing multiple copies of each transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tab1.ID,
       (SELECT SUM(tab2.amount) FROM tab2 WHERE tab2.id=tab1.id AND tab2.startdate<=tab1.transdate AND tab1.transdate<=tab2.enddate),
       (SELECT SUM(tab3.amount) FROM tab3 WHERE tab3.id=tab1.id AND tab3.startdate<=tab1.transdate AND tab1.transdate<=tab3.enddate)
FROM tab1
```

Comment: I got trouble with this solution... Please, see my updated original post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this SQL bro, hope it will work

```
SELECT
  A.customer_id,
  (SELECT
     SUM(B.transaction_amount)
   FROM tab2 B
   WHERE B.customer_id = A.customer_id
       AND B.transaction_date >= A.start_date
       AND B.transaction_date <= A.end_date
   GROUP BY B.customer_id) AS TAB2_amount,
  (SELECT
     SUM(C.transaction_amount)
   FROM tab3 C
   WHERE C.customer_id = A.customer_id
       AND C.transaction_date >= A.start_date
       AND C.transaction_date <= A.end_date
   GROUP BY C.customer_id) AS TAB3_amount
FROM tab1 A
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution, but when I put in the where condition the column from the table outside the subquery I get the following error: "Relation 'LM' does not exist", where LM is the name I gave to the table outside the subquery. this is the query I'm trying to run: